# Calculation not a method of Application or ActiveWorkbook

Tags: excel, vba, ms-project

I writing this code in MS-Project, but I thought I included all the necessary libraries to interface with Excel.

Here's what I have tried:

```
Sub OpenBackupFile()
    Titler = ActiveProject.CustomDocumentProperties("Title").Value
    BackupFile = "C:\POAMLogs\" & Titler & ".xlsx"


    'Set ExcelBackerp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    Set ExcelBackerp = New Excel.Application
    With ExcelBackerp

        .Calculation = xlCalculationManual

        .EnableEvents = False
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .DisplayAlerts = False
        .Workbooks.Open BackupFile

    End With

End Sub
```

No matter what I do I get, **Method "Calculation" of Object "_Application" Failed**
I can get intellisense to give me the first one as an option, but in the second one 'calculation' doesn't show up in intellisense.

Comment: I googled " Method "Calculation" of Object "_Application" Failed" and got helpful results.

Comment: @nicomp None of them applied to my situation/worked as far as I could tell.

Comment: Are you late binding or early binding - you've got `Set ExcelBackerp = CreateObject...` and `Set ExcelBackerp = New...`. Pick 1 and go with it.

Comment: `.Calculation` is not a part of `Workbook`. it is of `Application`

Comment: @BigBen Thanks for pointing that out. I've commented out one, but I'm still getting the error.

Comment: Try opening the workbook first before changing the `Calculation`

Comment: @Robofan Why not just do `With Application` instead of `With ExcelBackerp`?

Comment: @SiddharthRout That's what I thought since intellisense wouldn't show it to me for Workbook, but it did show me .Calculation = xlCalculationManual on Application, and yet still give me the error.

Comment: @dwirony no - what `Application` would that be? The new instance of Excel or the existing instance of MS Project?

Comment: @BigBen Then the workbook would have a chance to calculate, and I'm currently referencing a workbook that has calculation errors.

Comment: @SiddharthRout Nope, still get the error.

Comment: @BigBen Ah I'm not familiar with MS-Project, I didn't know what the aim was here...

Comment: @dwirony No worries, MS-Project is a pain in the boot, and its documentation too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I can get intellisense to give me the first one as an option, but in the second one 'calculation' doesn't show up in intellisense.

That is because `.Calculation` is not a property of `Workbook`. It is of `Application`

You can use `ExcelBackerp.Calculation = xlCalculationManual` but not `ExcelBackerp.ActiveWorkbook.Calculation = xlCalculationManual`

Also remember if you ever use latebinding then change `xlCalculationManual` to `-4135`

You are getting an error because you are trying to set the calculation when there is no workbook.

Try this and it will work

```
Set ExcelBackerp = New Excel.Application
ExcelBackerp.Workbooks.Add   
ExcelBackerp.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
```

So in your code open the workbook first and then set the calculation. :)

```
Sub OpenBackupFile()
    Titler = ActiveProject.CustomDocumentProperties("Title").Value
    BackupFile = "C:\POAMLogs\" & Titler & ".xlsx"

    'Set ExcelBackerp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    Set ExcelBackerp = New Excel.Application
    With ExcelBackerp
        .Workbooks.Open BackupFile
        .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
        .EnableEvents = False
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .DisplayAlerts = False
    End With
End Sub
```

or better, declare your variables/objects. will make your life easier :)

```
Sub OpenBackupFile()
    Titler = ActiveProject.CustomDocumentProperties("Title").Value
    BackupFile = "C:\POAMLogs\" & Titler & ".xlsx"

    Dim ExcelBackerp As Excel.Application
    Dim wb As Excel.Workbook

    Set ExcelBackerp = New Excel.Application

    With ExcelBackerp
        Set wb = .Workbooks.Open(BackupFile)

        .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
        .EnableEvents = False
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .DisplayAlerts = False
    End With

    '~~> Work with the workbook here
    With wb

    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked. If I add a workbook, and then open the desired one, will I need to close two workbooks at the end of my macros?

Comment: I added a workbook as an example. You can open your workbook. Refreshthe page and see my recent edit :)